# How to prevent obtained string in an array from reiterating in a nested for loop?

Tags: android-studio

I am making an app where all google applications should appear in listview. And I have added a nested for loop to sort out apps. However those apps i have sorted out are reiterating in for loops and each result has been displayed multiple times in list view.

```
 @Override
    protected List<AppInfo> doInBackground(Integer... params) {
        List<AppInfo> apps = new ArrayList<>();
        PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
        List<ApplicationInfo> infos = packageManager.getInstalledApplications(params[0]);
        String[] Googleapps = {"YouTube", "Google", "Gmail", "PlayStore"};
        for (ApplicationInfo info : infos) {
            if (mIncludeSystemApps && (info.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) == 1) {

            } else {
                for (int i = 0; i <= Googleapps.length; i++) {
                    for (String eachapp : Googleapps) {
                        if (info.loadLabel(packageManager).equals(eachapp)) {
                            AppInfo app = new AppInfo();
                            app.info = info;
                            app.label = info.loadLabel(packageManager).toString();
                            apps.add(app);


                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return apps;

    }
```

[Screenshot of app in mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNj3t.png)
apps are displayed repeatedly in phone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution! this line of code is causing it.
for (int i = 0; i <= Googleapps.length; i++) {}

After removing this line, it worked fine! thank you.